# Average shape of Voronoi cells in dimension $n\ge 2$?

Tags: poisson-process, voronoi-diagram

A Poisson point proess of constant intensity in $\mathbb R^n$ has a Voronoi diagram.  It is known that when $n=2$ the average number of edges of a cell is exactly $6$.  Last I heard (but that was a while ago), the probability distribution of the number of edges was not known in closed form.

It seems in some vague sense the average shape of a cell when $n=2$ is a regular hexagon.

So:

- Can the "average shape" statement be made precise and proved?
- What is the "average shape", and what is the average number of facets, when $n\ge 3$?